# Write Compile Time Dependencies to a File

Tags: java, groovy, gradle

I'm trying to go through the dependencies of a project and write those in a custom file.

I'm familiar with the way you create a fat jar, using the 'jar' plugin, but a similar approach in a custom task seems to not work.

Some of the code that I've tried.

```
// First way I tried to do it. 
task customTask(){
    File manifest = new File('file.txt')
    manifest << 'Some Text\n'
    manifest << 'Dependencies:'

    configurations.runtime.collect{ manifest << it.name}

}

// The second way I tried to do it. 
task manifest(){
    File manifest = new File('file.txt')
    manifest << 'Header\n'
    manifest << 'Dependencies:'
    FileTree tree = fileTree(dir: configurations.compile, include: '**/*.jar')
    tree.each {File file ->
        manifest << file
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want the runtime configuration in the first try. I you change to compile like you second example then you should get all the jars.  configurations.compile.collect{ manifest << it.name << "\n"}

Comment: Could you please clarify what you're trying to achieve? Basically those task won't work since there're no *actions*.

Comment: Opai, I want a file that in text has all the names of the jars that I need to compile and run my build.

Comment: Your tasks are setup for the *configuration* phase only, they just won't do anything when *run*. There needs to be either `<<` after task name, or everything put in a `doLast()` block (former is better in this case as you have no task type). Also they are writing to the same file during the configuration phase so will overlap/overwrite each other.

Comment: tobad357 That is what I would have thought but I get this error when doing it like you suggested.  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/davidtaylor/Workspace/plugin/build.gradle' line: 87

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'plugin'.
> Cannot change configuration ':compile' after it has been resolved.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

Comment: @MarkFisher I apologize for the confusion. The two tasks are two different attempts to get what I want. I only want one task. I'm going to try your advice though. Thanks

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure, you know you can run `gradle dependencies` and just redirect the output to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Configuration](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/Configuration.html) object returned from configuration.runtime is already a [FileCollection](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) interface, so you can readily iterate over it. This is why your fileTree(dir: xxx) didn't work, as that takes a directory path and creates a list of files, but the Configuration already is one.

The following worked for me:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'
dependencies {
    // compile gradleApi()
    compile 'junit:junit:4.11'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

task t1 << {
    def manifest = project.file('file.txt')
    manifest.delete()
    manifest << 'Dependencies:\n'

    // you can use it.path here if you need full path to jar
    configurations.runtime.each { manifest << it.name + "\n"}

    // also configurations.compile.each works here
}
```

It output the following:

```
Dependencies:
junit-4.11.jar
hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
```

Uncommenting the line `compile groovyApi()` in the dependencies, and it pulls a lot more jars in.

Generally I always use `project.file()` (you can just use `file()` but i like to be verbose on project methods) for creating file objects, rather than `new File(foo)`.

As suggested by Peter Ledbrook in the comments below, there are some further optimisations you could do to this task, particularly around making your file an output of the task, so that if the inputs of the task haven't changed, your file doesn't need to be recreated, and the job will skip. So the above is fairly raw.

Comment: Suggested improvements: (1) use File.withPrintWriter() to open the file once and ensure it's closed after everything is written. (2) Link to the DSL guide on `Configuration` so readers can find out what properties and methods are available on the `configurations.<conf>` object. I'd also make the output file a property to encourage good practice, but it's not that important :)

Comment: yes, i was just after a raw working prototype, as I couldn't understand what the initial problem actually was. There's tons of room for improvement

Comment: This worked perfect for me. I'm super grateful you took that time to help.

Comment: As per @PeterLedbrook comments I've added some links for the API to help explain why the fileTree wasn't working. Also, you should use `each` instead of `collect` if you're ignoring the return. The former just iterates, the latter is for creating a new object by manipulating every entry in the list. I update my code accordingly with comments about using `configurations.runtime` vs `configurations.compile`, both of which gave same results in my runs. You can of course also use `it.path` instead of `it.name` if you need the full path to each jar file. But thanks for accepting my answer anyway :)